# calling a procedure from another procedure in sqlserver

Tags: stored-procedures

i have 2 procedures procgetid,insertmarks.procgetid returns a int value which will be used in insertmarks procedure

`code in procgetid procedure`:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[procgetid](@sid int output)
as  
begin
select @sid=(select isnull(max(id),0)+100 from test2);
return @sid
end
```

`code in insertmarks procedure`:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[insertmarks](@sub1 int,@sub2 int,@sub3 int)
as 
declare @student_id int
begin
exec @student_id = procgetid
insert into marks values(@sub1,@sub2,@sub3,@student_id)
end
```

while executing insertmarks procedure i got an error
"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'student_id',column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails."

Answer (score 3):

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[insertmarks](@sub1 int,@sub2 int,@sub3 int)
as 
declare @student_id int
```

begin
   **set @student_id = exec [schemaname].procgetid**
   insert into marks values(@sub1,@sub2,@sub3,@student_id)
   end